# How to add for loops in python, in order to not to write the same thing all over?

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

```
name = raw_input("Please enter your name, so that I know how to address you!" " ")

semester = int(raw_input("Nice to meet you" + " " + name + ", " + "please tell me, how many semesters have you completed?" " "))





if semester == 1 :

    num1 = float(input("Ok" + " " + name + ", " + "please enter your 1-st semester GPA: "))

    a = float(num1)/1

    if a >= 3.5 :

        print "Good job " + name + ", " + "your GPA is great!"

    if a > 3 and a <3.5 :

        print "Nice, but I am sure you can do better," + " " + name + "."

    if a <= 3 and a > 2 :

        print name + " " + "don't give up! You should try harder!"

    if a <= 2 :

        print name + " " + "you better work harder, or you will be on probation!"

    print name + "'s" + " overall GPA is" + " " + str(a)



elif semester == 2 :

    num1 = float(input("Ok" + " " + name + ", " + "please enter your 1-st semester GPA: "))

    num2 = float(input("Enter your 2-nd semester GPA: "))

    a = float(num1 + num2)/2

    if a >= 3.5 :

        print "Good job " + name + ", " + "your GPA is great!"

    if a > 3 and a <3.5 :

        print "Nice, but I am sure you can do better," + " " + name + "."

    if a <= 3 and a > 2 :

        print name + " " + "don't give up! You should try harder!"

    if a <= 2 :

        print name + " " + "you better work harder, or you will be on probation!"

    print name + "'s" + " overall GPA is" + " " + str(a)



elif semester == 3 :

    num1 = float(input("Ok" + " " + name + ", " + "please enter your 1-st semester GPA: "))

    num2 = float(input("Enter your 2-nd semester GPA: "))

    num3 = float(input("Enter your 3-rd semester GPA: "))

    a = float(num1 + num2 + num3)/3

    if a >= 3.5 :

        print ("Good job " + name + ", " + "your GPA is great!")

    if a > 3 and a <3.5 :

        print ("Nice, but I am sure you can do better," + " " + name + ".")

    if a <= 3 and a > 2 :

        print (name + " " + "don't give up! You should try harder!")

    if a <= 2 :

        print (name + " " + "you better work harder, or you will be on probation!")

    print(name + "'s" + " overall GPA is" + " " + str(a))



elif semester == 4 :

    num1 = float(input("Ok" + " " + name + ", " + "please enter your 1-st semester GPA: "))

    num2 = float(input("Enter your 2-nd semester GPA: "))

    num3 = float(input("Enter your 3-rd semester GPA: "))

    num4 = float(input("Enter your 4-th semester GPA: "))

    a = float(num1 + num2 + num3 + num4)/4

    if a >= 3.5 :

        print ("Good job " + name + ", " + "your GPA is great!")

    if a > 3 and a <3.5 :

        print ("Nice, but I am sure you can do better," + " " + name + ".")

    if a <= 3 and a > 2 :

        print (name + " " + "don't give up! You should try harder!")

    if a <= 2 :

        print (name + " " + "you better work harder, or you will be on probation!")

    print(name + "'s" + " overall GPA is" + " " + str(a))



elif semester == 5 :

    num1 = float(input("Ok" + " " + name + ", " + "please enter your 1-st semester GPA: "))

    num2 = float(input("Enter your 2-nd semester GPA: "))

    num3 = float(input("Enter your 3-rd semester GPA: "))

    num4 = float(input("Enter your 4-th semester GPA: "))

    num5 = float(input("Enter your 5-th semester GPA: "))

    a = float(num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5)/5

    if a >= 3.5 :

        print ("Good job " + name + ", " + "your GPA is great!")

    if a > 3 and a <3.5 :

        print ("Nice, but I am sure you can do better," + " " + name + ".")

    if a <= 3 and a > 2 :

        print (name + " " + "don't give up! You should try harder!")

    if a <= 2 :

        print (name + " " + "you better work harder, or you will be on probation!")

    print(name + "'s" + " overall GPA is" + " " + str(a))



elif semester == 6 :

    num1 = float(input("Ok" + " " + name + ", " + "please enter your 1-st semester GPA: "))

    num2 = float(input("Enter your 2-nd semester GPA: "))

    num3 = float(input("Enter your 3-rd semester GPA: "))

    num4 = float(input("Enter your 4-th semester GPA: "))

    num5 = float(input("Enter your 5-th semester GPA: "))

    num6 = float(input("Enter your 6-th semester GPA: "))

    a = float(num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6)/6

    if a >= 3.5 :

        print ("Good job " + name + ", " + "your GPA is great!")

    if a > 3 and a <3.5 :

        print ("Nice, but I am sure you can do better," + " " + name + ".")

    if a <= 3 and a > 2 :

        print (name + " " + "don't give up! You should try harder!")

    if a <= 2 :

        print (name + " " + "you better work harder, or you will be on probation!")

    print(name + "'s" + " overall GPA is" + " " + str(a))



elif semester == 7 :

    num1 = float(input("Ok" + " " + name + ", " + "please enter your 1-st semester GPA: "))

    num2 = float(input("Enter your 2-nd semester GPA: "))

    num3 = float(input("Enter your 3-rd semester GPA: "))

    num4 = float(input("Enter your 4-th semester GPA: "))

    num5 = float(input("Enter your 5-th semester GPA: "))

    num6 = float(input("Enter your 6-th semester GPA: "))

    num7 = float(input("Enter your 7-th semester GPA: "))

    a = float(num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6 + num7)/7

    if a >= 3.5 :

        print ("Good job, " + name + ", " + "your GPA is great!")

    if a > 3 and a <3.5 :

        print ("Nice, but I am sure you can do better," + " " + name + ".")

    if a <= 3 and a > 2 :

        print (name + " " + "don't give up! You should try harder!")

    if a <= 2 :

        print (name + " " + "you better work harder, or you will be on probation!")

    print(name + "'s" + " overall GPA is" + " " + str(a))



elif semester == 8 :

    num1 = float(input("Ok" + " " + name + ", " + "please enter your 1-st semester GPA: "))

    num2 = float(input("Enter your 2-nd semester GPA: "))

    num3 = float(input("Enter your 3-rd semester GPA: "))

    num4 = float(input("Enter your 4-th semester GPA: "))

    num5 = float(input("Enter your 5-th semester GPA: "))

    num6 = float(input("Enter your 6-th semester GPA: "))

    num7 = float(input("Enter your 7-th semester GPA: "))

    num8 = float(input("Enter your 8-th semester GPA: "))

    a = float(num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6 + num7 + num8)/8

    if a >= 3.5 :

        print ("Good job, " + name + ", " + "your GPA is great!")

    if a > 3 and a <3.5 :

        print ("Nice, but I am sure you can do better," + " " + name + ".")

    if a <= 3 and a > 2 :

        print (name + " " + "don't give up! You should try harder!")

    if a <= 2 :

        print (name + " " + "you better work harder, or you will be on probation!")

    print(name + "'s" + " overall GPA is" + " " + str(a))



else:

    print "Please enter a valid semester number e.g. 1,2,3,...7,8"



import sys

while True:

    print('Type q to exit.')

    response = input()

    if response == 'q':

        sys.exit()

        print('You typed ' + response + '.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let's do this step by step:

### 1. Using functions to avoid dublicated code

You're using the exact same code for printing the output message, so this should become a function.

```
def print_response(name, a):
    if a >= 3.5 :
        print ("Good job, " + name + ", " + "your GPA is great!")
    if a > 3 and a <3.5 :
        print ("Nice, but I am sure you can do better," + " " + name + ".")
    if a <= 3 and a > 2 :
        print (name + " " + "don't give up! You should try harder!")
    if a <= 2 :
        print (name + " " + "you better work harder, or you will be on probation!")
    print(name + "'s" + " overall GPA is" + " " + str(a))
```

Using this function already improves the code, see below:

```
name = raw_input("Please enter your name, so that I know how to address you!" " ")
semester = int(raw_input("Nice to meet you" + " " + name + ", " + "please tell me, how many semesters have you completed?" " "))

def print_response(a):
    if a >= 3.5 :
        print ("Good job, " + name + ", " + "your GPA is great!")
    if a > 3 and a <3.5 :
        print ("Nice, but I am sure you can do better," + " " + name + ".")
    if a <= 3 and a > 2 :
        print (name + " " + "don't give up! You should try harder!")
    if a <= 2 :
        print (name + " " + "you better work harder, or you will be on probation!")
    print(name + "'s" + " overall GPA is" + " " + str(a))

if semester == 1 :
    num1 = float(input("Ok" + " " + name + ", " + "please enter your 1-st semester GPA: "))
    a = float(num1)/1
    print_response(a)

elif semester == 2 : 
    num1 = float(input("Ok" + " " + name + ", " + "please enter your 1-st semester GPA: "))
    num2 = float(input("Enter your 2-nd semester GPA: "))
    a = float(num1 + num2)/2
    print_response(a)

elif semester == 3 :
    num1 = float(input("Ok" + " " + name + ", " + "please enter your 1-st semester GPA: "))
    num2 = float(input("Enter your 2-nd semester GPA: "))
    num3 = float(input("Enter your 3-rd semester GPA: "))
    a = float(num1 + num2 + num3)/2
    print_response(a)

elif semester == 4 :
    num1 = float(input("Ok" + " " + name + ", " + "please enter your 1-st semester GPA: "))
    num2 = float(input("Enter your 2-nd semester GPA: "))
    num3 = float(input("Enter your 3-rd semester GPA: "))
    num4 = float(input("Enter your 4-th semester GPA: "))
    a = float(num1 + num2 + num3 + num4)/4
    print_response(a)

elif semester == 5 :
    num1 = float(input("Ok" + " " + name + ", " + "please enter your 1-st semester GPA: "))
    num2 = float(input("Enter your 2-nd semester GPA: "))
    num3 = float(input("Enter your 3-rd semester GPA: "))
    num4 = float(input("Enter your 4-th semester GPA: "))
    num5 = float(input("Enter your 5-th semester GPA: "))
    a = float(num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5)/5
    print_response(a)

elif semester == 6 :
    num1 = float(input("Ok" + " " + name + ", " + "please enter your 1-st semester GPA: "))
    num2 = float(input("Enter your 2-nd semester GPA: "))
    num3 = float(input("Enter your 3-rd semester GPA: "))
    num4 = float(input("Enter your 4-th semester GPA: "))
    num5 = float(input("Enter your 5-th semester GPA: "))
    num6 = float(input("Enter your 6-th semester GPA: "))
    a = float(num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6)/6
    print_response(a)

elif semester == 7 :
    num1 = float(input("Ok" + " " + name + ", " + "please enter your 1-st semester GPA: "))
    num2 = float(input("Enter your 2-nd semester GPA: "))
    num3 = float(input("Enter your 3-rd semester GPA: "))
    num4 = float(input("Enter your 4-th semester GPA: "))
    num5 = float(input("Enter your 5-th semester GPA: "))
    num6 = float(input("Enter your 6-th semester GPA: "))
    num7 = float(input("Enter your 7-th semester GPA: "))
    a = float(num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6 + num7)/7
    print_response(a)

elif semester == 8 :
    num1 = float(input("Ok" + " " + name + ", " + "please enter your 1-st semester GPA: "))
    num2 = float(input("Enter your 2-nd semester GPA: "))
    num3 = float(input("Enter your 3-rd semester GPA: "))
    num4 = float(input("Enter your 4-th semester GPA: "))
    num5 = float(input("Enter your 5-th semester GPA: "))
    num6 = float(input("Enter your 6-th semester GPA: "))
    num7 = float(input("Enter your 7-th semester GPA: "))
    num8 = float(input("Enter your 8-th semester GPA: "))
    a = float(num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6 + num7 + num8)/8
    print_response(a)

else:
    print "Please enter a valid semester number e.g. 1,2,3,...7,8"


import sys
while True:
    print('Type q to exit.')
    response = input()
    if response == 'q':
        sys.exit()
        print('You typed ' + response + '.')
```

### 2. Using a for loop

You can avoid typing the code for each number of semesters by using a for loop:

```
name = raw_input("Please enter your name, so that I know how to address you!" " ")
semester = int(raw_input("Nice to meet you" + " " + name + ", " + "please tell me, how many semesters have you completed?" " "))

def print_response(a):
    if a >= 3.5 :
        print ("Good job, " + name + ", " + "your GPA is great!")
    if a > 3 and a <3.5 :
        print ("Nice, but I am sure you can do better," + " " + name + ".")
    if a <= 3 and a > 2 :
        print (name + " " + "don't give up! You should try harder!")
    if a <= 2 :
        print (name + " " + "you better work harder, or you will be on probation!")
    print(name + "'s" + " overall GPA is" + " " + str(a))

if semester > 8 or semester < 1:
    print "Please enter a valid semester number e.g. 1,2,3,...7,8"
else:
    grade_sum = 0
    grade_sum += float(input("Ok" + " " + name + ", " + "please enter your 1-st semester GPA: "))
    for i in range(2, semester+1):
        suffix = "-nd" if i == 2 else "-rd" if i == 3 else "-st"
        grade_sum += float(input("Enter your {}{} semester GPA: ".format(i, suffix)))

    a = grade_sum / semester
    print_response(a)


import sys
while True:
    print('Type q to exit.')
    response = input()
    if response == 'q':
        sys.exit()
        print('You typed ' + response + '.')
```